# EventListener AS3 problems reset problems

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, addeventlistener

Hey guys I am having a problem with Event Listeners in my AS3 file. I am trying to make this object that lasts for 83 frames to appear in a different location every time the parent (83 frame) movie clip resets. The problem is I have a function that places the object at a random y value which works great once. When it resets the ojbect appears on the same Y point. This is because I removeEventListener the function otherwise the object goes shooting off the screen when it loads. How do I call that event listener again without causing a loop that will shoot the object off screen?

Here is my code:

```
import flash.events.Event;
stop();
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SeaWeedPostion);
//stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, SeaWeedPostion);



function SeaWeedPostion(e:Event):void{
//  if(newSeaWeed == 1) {
var randUint:uint = uint(Math.random() *500  + 50);
this.seaweedSet.y += randUint;
trace(randUint);

stopPos();
//}else{
    //nothing
//  }
}

function stopPos():void{
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SeaWeedPostion);
//var newSeaWeed = 0;
}

function resetSeaWeed():void{
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, SeaWeedPostion);
}
```

I have some // code in there from trying different things.
Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

ENTER_FRAME event is triggered every frame, so rather than changing position on each frame maybe it's better to create a counter, count frames and if it reaches 82 change position of SeaWeed.

```
var counter:uint = 0;
```

Now add `ENTER_FRAME` listener

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

function SeaWeedPostion(e:Event):void {
    counter++;

    //Are we there yet?
    if(counter < 83) {
        //Nope, carry on
    }
    else {
        //Yey!
        changePosition();
        counter = 0;
    }
}

//Reset SeaWeed position when called
function changePosition() {
    var randUint:uint = uint(Math.random() *500  + 50);
    this.seaweedSet.y += randUint;
    trace(randUint);
}
```